# Don't automatically Unsubscribe from feeds in Thunderbird after HTTP errors

Tags: thunderbird, feed-reader

I use [Thunderbird as a Feed Reader](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-subscribe-news-feeds-and-blogs), and though I can't find documentation for the feature, it seems to me that Thunderbird has a feature that automatically disables the automatic refresh of a feed if it has a problem accessing the feed. This may help some people, but I have been finding that if I resume my PC, often Thunderbird will query my feeds before my computer has restored its Internet connection, and thus disable automatic retrieval of all of my Feeds. To restore the automatic updates, I have to locate each Feed and set its `Check for new articles every` Setting. How do I disable this feature or behavior?

On Thunderbird 68.6.0, I find this setting in `Account Settings > Feeds > Manage Subscriptions...` with the `Check for new articles every` prompt for every Feed.

Comment: Doubt there's a way to disable it. It seems to be an annoying "feature" added in Thunderbird 60, as noted in the fifth item of the Advanced Tips section of [How to Subscribe to News Feeds and Blogs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-subscribe-news-feeds-and-blogs).

Comment: Ha, on the very page I linked! I wonder if the new feature from TB 60 was the automatic disable, or the icon that indicated an error.